# mvc 4 razor custom client side validation before httppost in Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, client-side

i am using ajax.beginform in my view.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtCardNumber">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button id="Search"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

on search button click instead of directly going to controller on HTTPPost i want to first do some client side validations on card number like check if has numbers and other custom validation. And if any validation fails i dont want to go to server side.
so i tried doing return false, but it hangs for a long time instead of being instantaneous. I tried event.preventdefault but i am unable to undo it and go to server side with proper values passing the model values.

```
$("#Search").button({.live("click", function (event) {
    var isvalid = SubmitValidations();
    if (isvalid) {        
 //show progress bar
        return true;
    } else {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        alert("Please correct the errors on the screen before proceeding.");
        return false;
    }
});
```

How to do custom client side validation and go to server side only if client side validation is successful.

Comment: if you debug the script is "isvalid" ever returning true?  event.preventDefault() should be working for you

Comment: yes it returns true when my custom validations pass. But event.preventDefault() has messed up its normal HTTPPost operation in case of true.

Comment: when you say messed up what do you mean?  in your question you say you are unable to go to the server with the proper values,  does it return but nothing returns?  I don't think you need the return lines in this case.  Does anything change when you remove them?

Comment: i put my answer back and added what fixed it.  If you click the check mark next to my answer you will give me points.  Very glad that it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

live has been deprecated.  your first line should be

```
$('#Search').on('click', function(event) {
```

also try removing return from the code.

Comment: sorry this is not working. It is redirecting to the server and doing the server side processing which should be avoided. Since the screen stopped hanging i assumed it was working.

Comment: when validation fails it just hangs at the jquery for a long time and keeps showing progress bar but does not go to server side, but in case validation passes it proceeds normally. How to avoid hanging. Its is going to jquery-1.8.3.js and looping through various things and so progress bar keeps showing.

Comment: when I have seen that it has been from a bug in the jquery code.  I don't see any more issues with the code that you have posted.  Try removing pieces of the code to see if things work.  The progress bar for example.  Try removing that and see if things start to work.  If you find an area having issues,  post the code and lets see if we can fix it

Answer (score 0):

I changed the helper method to specify an ID that I can hook into with jQuery:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("ActionName","ControllerName",FormMethod.Post, new {id = "submitForm"}))
    {
     //...
    }
```

Then jQuery:

```
       $('#submitForm').submit(function () {
            return validateFields(self);//false stops POST, true continues POST
        });
```